# Invisible link does not display if using java webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, mousemove

I have a block, "Categories". 
This block has a invisible config link (config link: `<a class="contextual-links-trigger" href="#">Configure</a>`)
When i manual move mouse to this block, config link become to `<a class="contextual-links-trigger contextual-links-trigger-active" href="#">Configure</a>` and config icon displays (base on the new class "contextual-links-trigger-active").
when i click config icon, link "Edit view" will display. (see image)

image link: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=448612048582483&set=a.152871061489918.29073.100003010769102&type=1&theater

I want to click link "Edit view" use java web driver. 
I used code below to display config icon but not successful:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath))).perform();
```

Please give me some ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `JavascriptExecuter` to click on the invisible link,

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('.contextual-links-trigger').click();");
```

then you can wait for visibility of **Edit View** and use **click**,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Edit view"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I used it for my context. it works well. here is my code:


JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;


js.executeScript("document.querySelector('#"+ block_id +" .contextual-links-trigger').classList.add('contextual-links-trigger-active');");‌​


new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.x‌​path(".//*[contains(@id, '"+block_id+"')]//a[contains(@class, 'contextual-links-trigger-active')]"))).click();

Comment: glad it helped..in stackoverflow its custom to accept the answer or upvote if it works, so that it will help others who refer this in future..